# Divergence of a certain improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $p<0$. Is it true (and if it is, then how to prove) that the improper integral:
$$
\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(e^x)dx}{\ln^p(1+x)}
$$
is conditionally divergent?

As far as I know, the integral:
$$
\int_1^{+\infty}f(x)dx
$$
can be conditionally convergent even if $f(x)$ is continuous but not bounded on $[1,+\infty)$. Therefore, I can't use that $f(x)$ in the integral above is not bounded to prove its divergence. Are there another ways to show it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:
If what you are asking is whether $\int^\infty_1 \Big|\frac{\sin(e^x)}{\log^p(1+x)}\Big|\,dx$

the change of variable $u=e^x$ gives you
$$
\int^\infty_e \frac{|\sin u|}{u\log^p(1+\log u)}\,du$$
The function $\log^p(\log u)$ increases very slowly in comparison to $u$ and (this needs a little justification), the integrand should be similar to $\frac{|\sin u|}{u}$.

---

Here is a sketch of a solution. Details are left to the OP.

Since $p<0$,

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_e \frac{|\sin u|\log^{-p}(1+\log u)}{u}\,du&\geq \log^{-p}(2) \sum^\infty_{n=1}\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{n\pi}\frac{|\sin u|}{u}\,du\\
&\geq \log^{-p}(2)\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{\pi(n+1)}\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{n\pi}|\sin u|\,du\\
&=\frac{ \log^{-p}(2)}{\pi}\Big(\int^\pi_0|\sin u|\,du\Big)\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

---

As for the existence of the limit $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_e \frac{\sin u\log^{-p}(1+\log u)}{u}\,du$, a similar method can break the integral  as an alternating series for which you may use standard results.